# C++ standard lib: Achieving constant time remove from linked list

Tags: c++, std

I would like to use standard library data structures (because one can easily override the Allocator) to get a (probably doubly) linked list that allows constant time removal operations **given a pointer to an element.**

Is this functionality built into any standard library data structures? Imagine the following list:

```
myList = [ elementA, elementB, elementC ]
```

Removing elementB is constant time in the size of the list if one can say something to this effect:

```
elementB.previous.next = pointer_to(elementC)
```

... or must I build my own linked list to achieve this?

Comment: You can't use a singly linked list, but a doubly linked one will work.

Comment: Given a *pointer* to an element, no. But everyone is answering as if you said "given an iterator". Is it important to the question that you only have a pointer, not an iterator?

Comment: Can you use an *iterator* instead of a *pointer* to the element?

Comment: If it is possible to have an iterator that will always point to an element regardless of its position in the list (i.e. regardless of whether or not that position changes), then I can use an iterator. Else, no.

Comment: @Zach Yes, list iterators will point to the same element even if the list is modified. Except when an element is erased, iterators pointing to that element will be invalid ofcourse.

Comment: @Zach: Yes, that's how iterators work (except when they're invalidated when containers like `vector` move elements around - but that doesn't happen to `list`). By design, they act like a pointer to a particular element of the container.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like iterators will work. How do I get an iterator to an element while inserting it, though? That will fulfill the 'given a [reference] to an element' bit.

Comment: @Zach: if you use insert it with `push_front`, then you get it with `begin()`. If you insert with `push_back`, you get it with `it=end(lst);--it;` or `rbegin()`. `insert_after` returns iterator to the newly inserted element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `std::list` supports constant-time removal of elements.

Quoting from documentation at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/:

> Lists are sequence containers that allow constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence, and iteration in both directions.

The implementation is indeed a doubly-linked list:

> List containers are implemented as doubly-linked lists; Doubly linked lists can store each of the elements they contain in different and unrelated storage locations. The ordering is kept by the association to each element of a link to the element preceding it and a link to the element following it.

To remove an element from a list, simply use the `erase()` member function:

```
std::list mylist;
std::list::iterator it = /* find an element */;

// remove the element in constant time
mylist.erase(it);
```

Comment: But this assumes you have the position. I have a pointer to the element, and not the position. Is it still possible to achieve constant time remove with `std::list` ?

Comment: @Zach (Edited/corrected) `mylist.remove(*ptrToItem);` will remove the item but is not constant time. You need an iterator to the item for this to work.

Comment: Is that constant time? Docs seem to indicate remove() iterates through the list (i.e., linear time) - or this is behavior undocumented? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/

Comment: @Zach: No, you'll have to work with iterators rather than pointers if you want to use standard containers.

Comment: @Zach You *can* do this with an iterator, just not with a pointer. You don't necessarily need to iterate over the entire list. Also note that behind the scenes, iterators are simply pointers anyway (that is, a single pointer is a list iterator's sole data member). (This is not guaranteed and is technically implementation-dependent, but all implementations I know of simply use a pointer. And this is not necessarily true of iterators for other data structures.)

Answer (score 3):

For a doubly-linked list, there's [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), which supports constant-time removal of an element given an iterator (but not a pointer) to that element.

C++11 added a singly-linked list, [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). That can't quite do what you describe: you can only remove an element in constant time if you have an iterator for the preceding element.

If you really want to manipulate containers using pointers to the elements, rather than iterators, then you'll have to abandon the non-intrusive STL model and use something like Boost's [intrusive containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive.html).

Comment: Interesting to know that O(1) removal without iterator/index exists in Boost intrusive (element.unlink()). I can only imagine this useful in some very limited usecases though... but the pattern seems popular among old C developers used to Win NT LINKED_LIST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563802(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 the using `iterator std::list::erase (const_iterator position)` is garantied to  be constant time. It you a doubly linked list. So this should fits your need.